List memoization issue on a personal project
I'm working on a personal project which is a simple Pokedex for Pokemons. I'm trying to memo the pokemonsList in the PokemonsTable.jsx component. So if I toggle a dark mode, the list of the Pokemons won't change, but for some reason there is a delay when I'm clicking on the toggle dark mode btn,
this is the link to me repo : https://github.com/yuvalmash/Pokedex
Any help would be match appreciated!

Maybe the delay is just the code running?
